# Using attr with pylint

Tags: python, pylint, python-attrs

Using the [attrs package](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) seems to cause errors with PyLint:

```
import attr

@attr.s(slots=True)
class Foo:
    d = attr.ib(attr.Factory(dict), type=dict)

f = Foo()

print('bar' in f.d)
print(f.d.items())
```

PyLint complains with the following error messages (irrelevant removed):

```
E:  9,15: Value 'f.d' doesn't support membership test (unsupported-membership-test)
E: 10, 6: Instance of '_CountingAttr' has no 'items' member (no-member)
```

Is there a direct way how to make attrs sanely work with pylint?

Comment: I was unable to reproduce this behavior (I used Python 3.6, `pylint` 1.8.1, `attrs` 17.3.0 on MacOS).

Comment: Forgot important part - there needs to be passed "slots=True" to decorator attr.s. Original post edited.

Comment: It seems you've run across a [known bug](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1694) in `pylint`. TL;DR: `pylint` currently doesn't support custom decorators.