# How can I let pylint know that an immutable object is an iterable type?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pylint, iterable

This question arises from my question ([Value [dict object] doesn't support membership test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75539194/value-dict-object-doesnt-support-membership-test?noredirect=1#comment133277046_75539194)) yesterday, where using `pylint` with `python2.7` is unable to recognize that an object is iterable.

I'll copy and paste the code from the above post here:

`file.py`

```
import attr

from base import BaseClass

@attr.s 
class MyClass(BaseClass):
  def set_ids(self, args):
    if id not in self.daily.obj_dict:
      # do some stuff
      print("testing")
```

`base.py`:

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from six import with_metaclass
from daily import Daily

class BaseClass(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, object)):
  @abstractmethod
  def set_ids(self, args):
    pass

  def process(self, vals, ids):
    obj_dict = {
      id: vals[id]
      for id in ids
    }

    self.daily = Daily(obj_dict)
```

`daily.py`:

```
import attr
from builtins import object

@attr.s(frozen=True)
class Daily(object):
    obj_dict = attr.ib(default=None)
```

`python2.7 -m pylint file.py` produces the error

```
E:  8,17: Value 'self.daily.obj_dict' doesn't support membership test (unsupported-membership-test)
```

I need to figure out how to silence this error, and I was thinking I could somehow tell the linter it's a `dict` or iterable type. How can I do this in `python2.7`?

Comment: You probably need some kind of plugin. Statically speaking, `obj_dict` isn't iterable; only the value ultimately assigned to the attribute by way of `attr.s` is.

Comment: As far as `pylint` is concerned, `obj_dict` is a class attribute with some non-iterable value.

Comment: @chepner But then why does `pylint` no longer give the same error if I remove the base class (see linked post) or if I removed the `frozen=True`? Why does it suddenly no longer think that `obj_dict` is some non-iterable value?